# postgresql-9.6 select update subtract

Tags: postgresql

I do not know how to explain what I am wanting to do.  So I will try and give as much detail as possible.

If I have a table like found here
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/axVoxD7CQNbchFDJCAgBpt/0
[Testme table](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/axVoxD7CQNbchFDJCAgBpt/0)

How would you do a select update subtracting 1 from counter column for each row?

Every time you run the select update all values from counter will drop by 1 until they reach counter value of 0?

I can do an update statement using rid column and update counter column by dropping the value in the column by one but this would require to many update statements.  I would like to find a way to run this on the whole table with just one select update!  Can this be done in PostgreSQL ??

Comment: `update testme set counter = counter - 1 where counter > 0`.

Comment: AWESOME !!!!  I could not figure it out... Thanks teppic!!!!